# Dynamically load PropertySources for instanciating JobScoped Beans

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I don't know if this is a crazy thing to do, and if this is even possible. There are different ways to do it manually, but I was trying to be lazy and see if Spring can do this for me.

I have a Spring Batch process, that requires configuration for each run. Since there are a lot of configurations available and from different sources (mainly different Git Repositories), depending on the jobParameters passed to the job.

Currently, when the job starts all my beans are defined with @JobScope. I'm using jGit to clone the configuration provided in the Job Parameters and I wanted to set a Pojo with @Value and @ConfigurationProperties.

Example:

```
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties
@Validated
public class MyConfiguration{
   @NotNull
   @Value("${myConfig1}")
   private String myConfig1;

   ...
}
```

Currently I'm using this code to add the propertySources to the environment:

```
val loader = new YamlPropertySourceLoader();
List<PropertySource<?>> list = loader.load(name, new FileSystemResource(path));
MutablePropertySources sources = env.getPropertySources();
for (val propertySource : list) {
    sources.addFirst(propertySource);
}
```

But if I start a second job in parallel the environment still has the propertySource added to the first job.

Is it possible to have a lay way to initialize this bean (and others that I will need later) with @Value but from a list of PropertySources only? Remember that I don't even know the location because it will be checked out to a temporary folder.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the requirement. Are you trying to dynamically add a bean to the context according to the job parameters passed to app?

Comment: yes. I need to create beans within the Job Scope. I can do that without problems. I would like to know if I can setup the initial values of the beans using the @Value annotation instead of trying to get manually the properties from a list of propertySources that must be populated in the job initialization.

Comment: I don't have a precise answer, but I think you can try to use `@Conditional` and implement a condition to define your bean dynamically. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think it will help.